# How to resolve conflict which arose after adding new jquery(jquery-3.1.1.js) version for implementing Bootstrap Modal

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal, conflict

`jquery-3.1.1.js` is conflicting with previous code. I added jquery-3.1.1.js to implement a Bootstrap Modal, but as a result the rest of the code is not working properly now.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>bootstrap-3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap-iso.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>bootstrap-3.3.7/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: We can't help you without seeing the broken code. However I'd assume you're using multiple versions of jQuery - don't do that.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I checked the code. I indeed have two versions of jQuery. But, what should I do to resolve this issue. Using only oneof them is not solving my problem. I will later update the quesion with broken Code.

Answer (score 0):

Using  `noConflict` allow you to use multipal verson of jquery . But I agree with Rory comment  **don't do that**.

See This old stackoverflow question [Can I use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)

Answer (score -1):

Change Your $ sign to JQuery or make your own name function